# How to align orthomosaics in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mosaic, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rgb, ground-control

I have processed about 8 orthomosaics from UAV data collection. They used RTK for georeferencing, but I guess it was not done properly. They did not use GCPs. Therefore, the orthomosaics do not align. This is mandatory since we need to create plot boundaries for the field.

How to align orthomosaics in QGIS? I have already tried the align raster option under Rasters > Align Rasters... and the were not aligned. For example, plot "A" on Mosaic 1 was 20 centimeters away on Mosaic 2.

[image: Error example]

Is there another tool or plugin that will align all of them?

Comment: "it did not work" is a poor information to work with. How are the results not satisfactory? My first guess would anyway be, to send those people back into the field and retake the imagery, including GCP this time.

Comment: @Erik I agree with you. Unfortunately, very often we receive the imagery dataset after they harvested. We cannot go back. I keep emphasizing the use of correct georeferencing...

Comment: Would you like to show an example of how they do not align or provide some data so others can investigate it?

Comment: You could try manually georeferencing the images in Layer -> Georeferencer